# Adding submodule in GitAhead

Tags: git-submodules, gitahead

Is there any documentation on how to add a submodule to a cloned repo in GitAhead. The submodule dialogue window shows an option for adding and removing submodules (`+`, `-` buttons) however they are not clickable.

GitAhead will read submodules created through a different application, however, the goal is to be able to fully manage submodules within GitAhead.

Answer (score 0):

I never got around to implementing submodule add and remove. The buttons are there because that was the intended interface.

Comment: I want to say thank you to those who contributed to the product as it is very easy to use. Thanks for confirming the feature availability, it would be an appreciated addition to have this supported.  Is there by  roadmap or planned date on when this feature will be available in the product?